# How would I create a command to shutdown my Discord.py Bot?

Tags: python, bots, discord, shutdown, replit

I have rewritten my existing Discord Bot so that commands work via `@client.command`.

Here is an example of the clear command so you can see how the language works.

```
@client.command()
async def echo(*args):
  output = ""
  for word in args:
    output += word
    output += " "
  await client.say(output)
```

I would like to create 2 commands.
One which will `-shutdown` the bot, taking it offline, and unresponsive. 
And the other which will `-restart` the bot, meaning that if I update the code, I run the restart command, and the bot will go offline, reboot, and then come back.

How would I go about doing this?

As I want the commands to only work for me, I have left by Discord User ID Below so you can include that in the code. `432234718860148749`.

Thanks in advance,
H

Comment: What operating system are you using to run your bot?  The easiest way to "restart" is to star another process that waits a few seconds (while your bot shuts down) and then starts your bot again.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I am using a Chrombook, running the code off of repl.it . How would I go about creating that code?

Comment: Hmm, I've never used repl.it for hosting.  That's going to make this more difficult. How do you start/stop your bot normally?  Is there some web api you could use to restart the bot?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh To start it I run the repl.it code. To stop, I change the token and edit the code. Which works since it's a private bot, but it takes quite some times.

Answer (score 2):

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.logout has your answer

```py
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def shutdown(ctx):
    await ctx.bot.logout()
```

However, I do not yet know how to restart a bot via a command

Answer (score 2):

As of the latest version—Discord.py 1.3.3—try this:

```
# Close the bot
@client.command(aliases=["quit"])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def close(ctx):
    await client.close()
    print("Bot Closed")  # This is optional, but it is there to tell you.
```